# jquery trigger click on other element

Tags: jquery

I had a look through others similar questions and I haven't got a clue why mine solution doesn't work. Maybe you can spot something I'm missing. What I'm trying to do is trigger a click while clicking on div with id badge

HTML

```
<div id="call-out">
    <div id="badge">Brochure</div>
    <p>Add <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">test</a> content</p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#badge').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    if (! $(e.target).is('a')) {
        $(this).parent('div').find("a").trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Any suggestions appreciated. Here is my test: http://jsfiddle.net/m89wa/2/

Comment: The click is working, as demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/m89wa/4/ It appears that the popup is not working.

Comment: I was assuming that it will take look for the href attribute and open it without doing window.location, maybe I was assuming wrongly.

Comment: Yeah, so if you're really looking for it to open a new window you can do a `window.open("")` or do what @jandro5 suggests below.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I will go with window.open() and read the href attribute from <a> element: http://jsfiddle.net/m89wa/5/

Answer (score 2):

change:
$(this).parent('div').find("a").trigger('click');

try:
location.href = $(this).parent('div').find("a").attr("href");

Comment: Good answer - add `window.open` as an alternative and this is what @trikess is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#badge').on('click', function(e) {
 e.stopImmediatePropagation();
 $(this).parent().find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m89wa/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you call the `click` function without an argument on a jquery element, it will trigger the click event on that element.

http://api.jquery.com/click/

```
$('#badge').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $(this).parent().find('a').click();       
});
```

Comment: The only difference is .click() instead of .trigger('click'). Not much difference, but it is a bit more succinct.

Comment: This does not answer the original question - he was looking to have it behave as if the <a> was clicked. Programmatically invoking click does not open the new window, which is the OP problem.

Comment: It actually *does* answer the original question, namely how to trigger a click event from another element. The extra requirement to open a separate window is something that you helped to sniff out in the comments after I'd given this answer.